# Problema con interfaz de vista previa en Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El caso es que cuando creo un proyecto al momento de agregar cualquier componente a la interfaz de vista previa no me deja verlo, solo me deja verlo si ejecuto la aplicacion en un emulador. A continuacion dejare una foto para que pueda quedar mas claro. Si alguien sabe la solucion me seria de mucha ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en ves de un relaitev layou preuba con un linear layou orientacion vertical para ver que no se problema del IDE y serviria ver mas el codigo de ese xml que la foto

Comment: Bro ya subi la foto del codigo xml

Comment: Me empezo a pasar eso cuando empezer a usar Fragments, no me pasaba antes

Comment: vuelvo a insistit que purebes con linear layout .. los dos elementos los tienes igual de alineados quita los aligparentstart y top

Comment: Ya lo hice y sigue igual, creo que es por un problema de renderizado

Comment: En la esquina derecha superior de la segunda imagen tienes un ícono de color rojo con alerta, ¿que mensaje te muestra si le pasas el ratón por encima o le das click?

Comment: Me dice "Render problem" un problema de renderizado

Comment: Cuando pasa eso, puede deberse a varios motivos, lo que puedes hacer es darle a Build->Clean and Build y ver si el proyecto se reconfigura correctamente, caso contrario te devolverá los errores en la consola.

Answer (score 1):

A mi pasa igual y exactamente nose cual es el error, para poder solucionarlo en el gradle estoy usando la version 27 o inferiores asi me muestra la previsualizacion tendrias que cambiar tambien todas las implementaciones de la dependencias a version de sdk 27 te pongo un ejemplo

```
pply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "asd.movimientolist"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('src/main/java/ksoap2.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si la `build` la hace correctamente, debería poder verse, de todas formas puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
- Build -> Clean Project,  
- Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Si sigue sin funcionar, cierra el emulador y

```
 Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Si persiste el error, prueba a hacer una reinstalación o incluso a actualizar el `IDE` a una versión estable.